# Procesos adicionales en el pool de conexiones a la base de datos al reconectar después de una desconexión

Tags: java, mariadb, jdbc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Java donde utilizo un pool de conexiones a una base de datos MariaDB. Para monitorear los procesos en ejecución, utilizo el comando `show processlist`. Aquí está el problema que enfrento: cuando abro el proyecto, se realiza una conexión y cuando la cierro, el proceso correspondiente desaparece correctamente. Sin embargo, si desconecto la conexión a Internet y vuelvo a conectarla, al ejecutar `show processlist` veo que hay dos procesos adicionales activos.

He verificado mi código en busca de posibles fugas de conexiones y he implementado la llamada al método `.close()` en todos los puntos necesarios. Sin embargo, no logro identificar el origen de estos dos procesos adicionales. Mi proyecto es bastante grande, lo que dificulta la búsqueda manual.

Además, cuando reviso la información proporcionada por `show processlist` para estos procesos adicionales, aparece como `null`. ¿Qué puede estar sucediendo o cómo puedo abordar este problema en mi proyecto Java?

Uso

```
import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource;
```

Comment: Qué usas para el **pool** de conexiones? Alguna librería o las creas a mano? Podrías poner **en la pregunta** la salida de ese comando cuando dices que hay procesos adicionales activos? Por favor responde a los comentarios yendo a [edit] tu pregunta y añadiendo la info

Comment: Tu arquitectura no es clara. ¿Usas algún framework?.

Comment: uso  la libreria import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quería dar una solución y es que si se va la conexión de internet, genera una conexión nueva y la antigua no se puede recuperar, es normal que pase esto y que la solución general que se hace para estas conexiones perdidas es que el workbench las elimina en un tiempo determinado. O sea, hacer un conexion.close no va a funcionar debido a que si pierdes la conexión, no vas a poder cerrarla, o por ejemplo si limpias la variable tampoco va a dejarte.